# How to execute multiple SQL queries concurrently in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have two tabs in MySQL Workbench's SQL Editor, each of them containing one SQL query: is there any way I can launch those two queries concurrently? I use Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate with MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 CE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is now possible. I'm using MySQL Workbench 6.2.5 on Ubuntu 14.04. To do so, select "New Tab to Current Server" from the [Query] drop down menu or press Ctrl+Shift+T. Get the latest version of the software by downloading it from the official website.

Answer (score 5):

In order to avoid excessive usage of connections all editors in a session share the same connection (there's another one in the background for maintenance tasks like killing a query, but in general you only have one at your disposal). What you can do however is to open multiple sessions to the same server. They can then run queries concurrently.

Comment: Thanks, I wish they let decide the user regarding the usage of connections. Opening multiple sessions to the same server indeed makes simultaneous queries possible but isn't very convenient. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?161,365676,365920#msg-365920 seems to say it might be simply a software limitation (not too sure if they are referring to the same issue), so maybe I'll add a feature request in the bug tracker if nobody has found a trick to execute multiple SQL queries concurrently in MySQL Workbench without opening multiple sessions.

Comment: Can you make a case for it? (i.e. why would MySQL Workbench users want such a feature?) Most software projects are unlikely to dedicate serious efforts to features that most users don't use.

Comment: Example 1: I want to run a query that is very CPU consuming and has a few IO at the same time as a query that isn't very CPU consuming and has many IO.

Comment: Example 2: I want to run a very quick query while a very long one is running so that I don't have to wait for the latter.